# What .NET-based reporting tools are best suited for an MVC web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

The Microsoft .NET web (MVC) application will include about 100 reports that will contain dynamically generated text w/ embedded data, images, static text, and tabular data. All reports need to be generated on-the-fly as user inputted data will drive the necessary content for the reports. The reports will be viewed as web pages and must be exported to a PDF file that the user can download.

Suggestions based upon your real-life experiences w/ tools appreciated.

Comment: You just described the basic requirements for every report library in existence, this question has been covered before ( check sidebar ), and is not really a good question for SO.

Comment: I reviewed a number of questions/answers before posting this question and found the answers either old (1+yr), not applicable to MSFT .NET MVC, or opinions rather than real-life experience. I am looking for feedback from someone who has actually used the tools w/ similar requirements to get a realistic appraisal of the tool capabilities.

Comment: The question is actually valid, as there may be limitations with some of the reporting engines in ASP.NET MVC (see my answer bellow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used SQL Reporting Services with success on that scenario. HOWEVER, I had to create an ASP.NET page to host the Report Viewer Control, as it requires ViewState and such.

If this is not an issue for you, I can garantee that it works quite well. The PDF generation is good and the excel export is fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. There will be a lot of calculations for the reports so a SQL Server based tool might fit well. It would also influence the application architecture, moving many calculations to the DB so they could be used for page and report generation.

Comment: Actually with reporting services you can feed a dataset to the report. You don't necessarily need to calculate everything DB-wise

Comment: psousa-thanks for the info. There already will be a significant # of complex DB functions for other purposes which is why I mentioned that approach.